# Convert javascript post function to angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i am start to learn about angular js. I have a javascript function which is post function, now i want to convert it to angular js.

Here is my old javascript code:

```
<script>
function submitFunction() {
    var ip_range = "";

    var user_name = "wind";

    $.post("software.aspx", {"action": "getchartdata","username": user_name},
        function(data, status) {

            if (status === "success") {
                if (data) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

                    dataParse(data);
                } else {
                    alert("ALERT!");
                }

                alert(start_date)
            }
            alert(start_date)


        });
}
</script>
```

I can get the return result from this old javascript, it return me the json result. Below is my new angular js function which couldnt works. I not sure whether i need to change the backend code.

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('FormCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

        console.log("Preparing..")
        $scope.submitForm = function () {
            console.log("posting data....");
            var username = $scope.form;
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'Software.aspx',
                data: {username: username},


            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                // this callback will be called asynchronously
                // when the response is available
                console.log("Success")
                console.log(response)

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
                console.log("fail")

            });

        };
    });
</script>
```

I wish someone to tell me what i less to convert into angular js. Thanks.

Comment: You have not specified the action in `url: 'Software.aspx',`

Comment: check your console log

Comment: What does not work? Do you have any HTTP status in result?

Comment: @doncadavona It is Angular 1, look at the code and the tag `angularjs`.

Comment: Oh yeah I see it's angularjs.

Comment: Check the error on your console log. Also check the response in the errorCallback: console.log(response).

Comment: I check my console log, but it canr get the response back from the server, could it be the problem of the header? I need to convert the header first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out this method could achieve the same result from the javascript.

```
 $scope.submitForm = function () {
            console.log($scope.selected)

            console.log(startDate)
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'Software.aspx',
                data: {
                    "action": "getchartdata",
                    "username": $scope.username,

                },
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                },
                transformRequest: function (data) {
                    return $.param(data);
                }
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                // this callback will be called asynchronously
                // when the response is available
                console.log(response);
                dataParse(response.data);


            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
                console.log("fail to send")

            });

        };
```

Need to set the headers to this:

```
 headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                    },
                    transformRequest: function (data) {
                        return $.param(data);
                    }
```

Then only this will works.